# Can you help me find the part number for this push button cap?

Tags: button

I've been searching high and low for the part number and manufacturer for this button cap. I've tried it out and it works perfectly for my project. Note: I do not want the button itself, as I've already found one that fits the "springiness" level that I need (Omrom B3F-5050, if you're curious -- they don't require as much force to press as others -- 1.27 N). Please note that these have a low-profile and slightly rounded/domed top (kind of shaped like a circular pill).

[Here's an Amazon link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008DGB71Y) for the cap I'm trying to find. I would like to be able to buy more of these, potentially in large quantities, but just the cap.

EDIT:
In order to make this question more useful for others, I'll reword it a bit: I'm looking for round, low-profile buttons to fit the Omron B3F-5050 push buttons. Any suggestions would be highly valued. I find that most button caps are tall, and sometimes folks need buttons that are lower-profile. The domed top is a "nice to have", but the low profile is most important.

Comment: What makes you think that if you get the cap off the generic switch that it will fit on the Omron switch?

Comment: That, I can't be sure of until I try it out by hand. From inspection, it looks like the plungers are the same. Unfortunately, there's not much data on the caps I like. A good solution would be round, low-profile caps (maybe less than 4mm height) that fit the Omron buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have to order them from an Omron supplier, and I'm not sure they've got caps like you want.  I find many different caps that will fit your switch at Mouser, and I'm pretty sure you can get them from other suppliers as well.  Whether you like Omron's caps is another question.

[This is a link to the Omron datasheet for the caps.](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/307/B32_0913-336225.pdf)

If the Omron caps aren't what you want, then you'll need to look for a dealer who sells Amico parts - that's who made the ones on Amazon.  I'm not finding them, though.

Assuming the Amico caps really fit the Omron switches, maybe someone else's caps will fit as well.
[E-Switch](https://www.e-switch.com/product-catalog/caps#.U2gkYVfLJgI) has caps much like the ones on Amazon.  Maybe they also have switches like you want, and caps as well.  E-Switch seems to have an enormous selection of caps.

Comment: I decided on a compromise and went with some square caps with E-Switch. The ones I'm going to try out are: 4JBLK (they are 12mm square and have a nice circular concavity in the center), and 6JBLK (they are 8mm square). Both have a low profile, which is very important. Based on the datasheets for the switches, they _should_ be compatible with the Omron plungers. I'll know for sure once they come in the mail.